# Sorting dates with moment.js does not work when date is a link

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I'm using DataTables 1.10.5. When I'm trying to sort on dates using the recommended `moment.js` (as per http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18), thinks work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gohzd9t/1/

However, when I add a link (`a href`) to that date, it sorts on the link instead of the date:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnsL2oc4/1/

Any idea on how to properly fix this without too much hacking around?

Comment: FYI, this was fixed in DataTables 1.10.6 and above. See https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/pull/171.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the unshift method of datetime-moment.js. `Moment` tries to convert `<a href="12.html">12-01-2001</a>` to a valid date in the given "DD-MM-YYYY"-Format, which it can't obviously. So you have to strip the html away from the date, probably with a function like this:

```
function strip(html) {
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

And then strip the string in the unshift method (Replace datetime-moment.js with the code below):

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment = function (format, locale) {
  var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

  // Add type detection
  types.detect.unshift(function (d) {                
      return moment(strip(d), format, locale, true).isValid() ?
          'moment-' + format :
          null;
  });

  // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
  types.order['moment-' + format + '-pre'] = function (d) {
    return moment(strip(d), format, locale, true).unix();
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Question though: is there a need to shorten down the `datetime-moment.js` file like the above? As simply adding the `strip()` function and calling it twice on `(d)` does the trick, no? See http://jsfiddle.net/dnsL2oc4/2/ .
Do you want to submit a pull request to DataTables? If not I can do.

Comment: @SaeX `datetime-moment.js` has only these two functions so it isn't really shortened, but yes calling `strip` twice is all I changed from the original. Feel free to submit a pull request if you want :).